# Cannot locate Freebase Java API libraries

Tags: java, freebase

I'm new to using freebase, so I'm going through the java sample provided on the [Developers page](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview). But when I run the code, I get errors because eclipse cannot recognize the packages that I'm importing. Does anyone know where I can download these packages in order to import them without errors. So my question is, where can I download the package com.freebase.samples
I've looked everywhere for the package but can't find it anywhere, is it discontinued and replaced by a newer package, if so does anyone know the name of the new package and where I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but the files have the package com.freebase.samples.

https://github.com/fatschi/FreebaseCrawl/tree/master/src/main/java/com/freebase/samples